# OAuth2.0 what should be the content format of refresh token, before encryption?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am developing an OAuth2.0 Server. What should be the format of refresh token and what encryption algo should be used for encryption?

Answer (score 5):

OAuth 2.0 does not enforce any restrictions regarding token formats or encryption. Encryption is completely disregarded in the spec, as communication is supposed to be secured with TLS.

Also - **don't implement yourself if you don't really have to**. Choose an open source library or even a vendor product if your funding permits it.

That being said, take a look at the [JWT RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519). That's the format most people use. You can also consider no format at all and just work with opaque strings, and then implement token introspection in your Authorization server.

As to encryption - anything goes. Most implementations out there support at the very least HS256, RS256 and ES256 for signing JWT tokens. In most real world scenarios you don't need to encrypt the token, a signature is enough.

Comment: This is solid advice, my only comment, I would put the don't implement it yourself in bold... :)

Answer (score 5):

After struggling for sometime, I figured it out. There are two approaches

1. Either put everything that you need to construct access token (apart from things that can be derived/calculated directly) in refresh token and encrypt it with global or tenant level symmetric key

   Benefits:

   a. No storage required

   b. Better performance as No contact with DB is required. It is just decryption and creation of access token

   Issues/shortcomings

   a. No way to keep track of refresh tokens issued.

   b. No way to invalidate the issued refresh tokens.
2. Storing attributes related to refresh token in DB and in response of OAuth Server, returning encrypted refresh token ID. Attributes that might be stored in DB are

   ID || Expiry || Count of Token || Subject || Client ID || Custom Attributes (If required)

There can be other attributes as well which we implemented but this must give a bit of idea to people who want to implement their own Refresh Token flow

Comment: If you aren't storing refresh tokens in a stateful place like a database, then there really isn't a point to even needing refresh tokens. The reason we have this extra complexity is to be able to revoke access. AFAIK having both tokens and refresh tokens be stateless does absolutely nothing